# Convert a Duration(ex. 3h 23m) to datetime in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

how can I convert time as string like this `2h 25m 15s` or `2h 10m` into a `datetime` or just minute like `1h => 60` using NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact duplicate for this, but we have many, many similar questions, all similar to [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5619202/215552). Basically, you just need to take a `Date` and add those values to it. I'd use `Date(0)` to keep it simple (uses the [ECMAScript epoch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#the_ecmascript_epoch_and_timestamps)).

Note I use some recent additions to JavaScript here:

- `?.` The ["optional chaining operator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) lets me pretend that `exec` on the regular expression will work. If not, the whole thing returns undefined.
- `??` The ["nullish coalescing operator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) handles the case when `exec` failed to find the unit and returns 0 instead ("nullish" refers to null or undefined).

```js
const durs = [
  '2h 25m 15s',
  '25m 15s',
  '15s',
  '2h 25m',
  '2h',
  '25m'
];

function parseDurationAsDate(duration) {
  const hours = parseInt(/(\d*)h/.exec(duration)?.[0] ?? 0, 10);
  const minutes = parseInt(/(\d*)m/.exec(duration)?.[0] ?? 0, 10);
  const seconds = parseInt(/(\d*)s/.exec(duration)?.[0] ?? 0, 10);
  const date = new Date(0); // date portion is irrelevant
  // especially if we use setUTCHours so that toISOString shows no offset
  date.setUTCHours(hours, minutes, seconds);
  return date;
}
for (let dur of durs) {
  console.log(`Duration:`, dur);
  let dt = parseDurationAsDate(dur);
  console.log('  Date:', dt.toISOString());
  console.log('  Time:', dt.toISOString().slice(11, -1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a function to split the time, with a regular expression (ReGex) in the specified structure (`{number}h {number}m {number}s`):

```js
const splitTime = time => time.match(/((?<hours>\d{1,2})(?:h))?\s?((?<minutes>\d{1,2})(?:m))?\s?((?<seconds>\d{1,2})(?:s))?/).groups;
```

This function accepts and expects an input in the `h m s` format, each letter preceded by number, then a regex expression is defined for this input, simply put the expression searches for a number (e.g.: **(expression 1)** `(?<hours>\d{1,2})`) that is followed by a letter (e.g.: **(expression 2)** `(?:h)`), but the letter not elegible to match within the group (expression `?:`), we make this expression optional with "?" at the end of the outermost parenthesis of the capturing group, like: `(expression 1 expression 2)?`, and finally we make the spaces in between optional with `\s?` (matching exactly one space in between).

Then we can create a function that accepts hours, minutes and seconds, with defaults to 0 (zero), like so:

```js
const timeToSeconds = ({hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0}) => Number(hours) * 60 * 60 + Number(minutes) * 60 + Number(seconds);
```

and then use with `splitTime` function:

```js
const seconds = timeToSeconds(splitTime('1h 25s'));
console.log(seconds); // 3625
```

Full code with additional functions:

```js
const splitTime = time => time.match(/((?<hours>\d{1,2})(?:h))?\s?((?<minutes>\d{1,2})(?:m))?\s?((?<seconds>\d{1,2})(?:s))?/).groups;

const timeToHours = ({hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0}) => Number(hours) + Number(minutes) / 60 + Number(seconds) / 60 * 60;

const timeToMinutes = ({hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0}) => Number(hours) * 60 * 60 + Number(minutes) + Number(seconds) / 60;

const timeToSeconds = ({hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0}) => Number(hours) * 60 * 60 + Number(minutes) * 60 + Number(seconds);

const time = "1h 15m 0s";
const timeSplit = splitTime(time);

console.log(timeToHours(timeSplit));
console.log(timeToMinutes(timeSplit));
console.log(timeToSeconds(timeSplit));

// Missing hours and seconds
console.log(timeToSeconds(splitTime("15m")));
```